# Python - Spilt Text by character group

Tags: python, regex, split

I'm trying tying to parse some text into pieces at every group of characters In my case the character groups would be "* ((" and ")) "

```
import re
file = "Name* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A40 & A41)) Name2* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A42 & A43)) Name3* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A44 & A45)) Name4* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A46 & A47)) Name5* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A48 & A49)) Name6* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A50 & A51)) Name7* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A452 & A53)) Name8* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A54 & A55)) Name9* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A56 & A57)) Name10* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A58 & A59)) Name11* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A60 & A61)) Name12* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A62 & A63)) Name13* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A64 & A65)) Name14* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A66 & A67)) Name14* ((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A68 & A69))"
parse = re.split('[* ((][)) ]', file)
print parse
```

My results come back as:

```
['Name', '((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A40 & A41)) Name2', '((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A42 & A43)) Name3', '((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A44 & A45)) Name4', '((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A46 & A47)) Name5', '((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A48 & A49)) Name6', '((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A50 & A51)) Name7', '((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A452 & A53)) Name8', '((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A54 & A55)) Name9', '((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A56 & A57)) Name10', '((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A58 & A59)) Name11', '((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A60 & A61)) Name12', '((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A62 & A63)) Name13', '((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A64 & A65)) Name14', '((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A66 & A67)) Name14', '((Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A68 & A69))']
```

It only seems to be splitting the text at the "*".  I can't seem to figure out how to setup more than one multi-character separators.  Anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: what are you actually trying to split on? Also are you sure you don't want findall?

Comment: I'm trying to split at every "* ((" and ")) ".  I honestly don't know if findall is what I want.  The text is essentially in one cell of a table, and I'm trying to parse it out into separate cells, and fields.

Comment: Do you want to keep the (( and )) or not? Do you want something like  `re.split('\*\s+\(\(|\)\)', file)`

Comment: That worked perfectly.  It removes the (( and )).  Thanks Padraic :)  There's quite a bit more I have to do with the text, but this gets me past the parsing part.

Comment: No worries, you can add it as an answer if it worked and get yourself some rep. You might also need to filter what it returns something like  `list(filter(None, (x .strip() for x in re.split('\*\s+\(\(|\)\)', file))))`, also if this is coming from a file you could actually do it without a regex quite easily

Answer (score 0):

I'd try following regex

```
import re
file = "your....string.... content" #your string goes here.

parse = re.split(r"\*|\)\)|\(\(", file)
```

> OUTPUT:
>
> ['Name', ' ', 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A40 & A41', ' Name2', ' ', 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A42 & A43', ' Name3', ' ', 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A44 & A45', ' Name4', ' ', 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A46 & A47', ' Name5', ' ', 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A48 & A49', ' Name6', ' ', 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A50 & A51', ' Name7', ' ', 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A452 & A53', ' Name8', ' ', 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A54 & A55', ' Name9', ' ', 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A56 & A57', ' Name10', ' ', 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A58 & A59', ' Name11', ' ', 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A60 & A61', ' Name12', ' ', 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A62 & A63', ' Name13', ' ', 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A64 & A65', ' Name14', ' ', 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A66 & A67', ' Name14', ' ', 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A68 & A69', '']

Comment: This  really just adds more whitespace only strings than what I suggested in the comments otherwise it is the same

Comment: Oh, I might have missed your comment.  I agree there is a lot more spaces and its natural based on OP requirement

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share the solution I ended up using in case anyone else could benefit.  There's a mixture of regex in there but I used findall instead of split.  Now that I've got this far I have to to look into controlling the output more.  The data gets dumped into 3 fields (From_Node, To_Node, Link).  I need the value from the first "To_Node" to become the value of the "From_Node" on the next row, and so on. Imagine points along a line, point A to B, then point B to C, then point C to D, etc....  With my limited knowledge I don't even know where to begin looking up this solution.  Any ideas?

```
import re, arcpy

# Local variables:
Table1 = "D:\Database1.mdb\\Table1"
RAW_Data = "D:\Database1.mdb\RAW_Data"

#Create Cursors and Insert Rows
insertcursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(Table1, ["From_Node", "To_Node", "Link"])
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(RAW_Data, ["Field1", "Field1", "Field1"]) as searchcursor:
    try: 
        for row in searchcursor:
            listFrom_Node = re.findall('\w+(?=\*\s*)', row[0]) #From Node
            print listFrom_Node
            print "From Node List Success"
            listTo_Node = re.findall('\w+(?=\*\s*)', row[1]) #To Node
            print listTo_Node
            print "To Node List Success"
            listLink = re.findall('\(\((.*?)\)\)', row[2]) #Link descriptions
            print listLink
            print "Link List Success"
            for n,Value in enumerate(listFrom_Node):
                insertcursor.insertRow((listFrom_Node[n], listTo_Node[n], listLink[n]))
    except:
        print ('Empty Cursor')
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you use split function for strings? That and some list comprehensions would do the job.

```
In[31]: [i for s in [s.split(')) ') for s in file.split('* ((')] for i in s]
Out[31]: 
['Name',
 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A40 & A41',
 'Name2',
 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A42 & A43',
 'Name3',
 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A44 & A45',
 'Name4',
 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A46 & A47',
 'Name5',
 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A48 & A49',
 'Name6',
 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A50 & A51',
 'Name7',
 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A452 & A53',
 'Name8',
 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A54 & A55',
 'Name9',
 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A56 & A57',
 'Name10',
 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A58 & A59',
 'Name11',
 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A60 & A61',
 'Name12',
 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A62 & A63',
 'Name13',
 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A64 & A65',
 'Name14',
 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A66 & A67',
 'Name14',
 'Bla Bla Bla (Bla Bla) A68 & A69))']
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Raf.  I think Padraic's answer gets me what I need.  I appreciate all the help

Comment: Raf, it looks like I'm finally getting a chance to get back to this.  Please pardon my lack of experience when I ask this question.  What do "i" and "s" represent?  Is "s" equivalent to "string"?  Like I said I'm pretty green with reagrds to variables, etc.

Comment: @user1457123 Hi, no problem. That's just a way of flattening a list of lists. Have a look here. [http://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/5069105]

Comment: So "i" = "item" and "s" = "sublist"? OK that makes sense.

Comment: So now I have to figure out how to insert the parsed data into certain fields within a table.  i.e. "Name..." in one field, and "Bla Bla Bla (Bla..." in another.  I'm currently dumping all of the output values into one field.  any suggestions on how I can direct the data traffic to go where I want?